# Axis2 problem after consume different webservice with https but only one uses certificate authentication

Tags: java, https, certificate, apache-axis

I have an Java Web Application, which consumes different WebServices.
Now I have to consume one WebService that needs both way authentication.
I use `SSLClientAxisEngineConfig` implementation (https://github.com/linhkuivanen/axistools) that I send as parameter to my class that extends `org.apache.axis.client.Service`.
It worked.
But only if it is the first use of some `Axis Client`.
After that, if I consume a WebService with 'https' that does not require certificate, I got error "Untrusted Server Certificate Chain".

If I consume first a Webservice that does not require certificate authentication, when I try to consume the other one that need authentication, I got "Handshake failure" error.

I assume that `Axis` has some kind of cache that reuses the first configuration, but I cannot figure out a way to solve my problem.

**Edit**: I solved the problem. 
I generated a new Axis Client with `wsdl2java` (Axis2-1.7.8), instead of using the Eclipse Web Service Client generator. Before consume the WebService, I register a new `https` protocol with client certificate and cacerts:

```
Protocol protocol = new Protocol("https", socketFactoryDinamico, 443);    
Protocol.registerProtocol("https", protocol);
```

and after using it, I unregister the protocol:

```
Protocol.unregisterProtocol("https");
```

After this, I can consume other WebServices without certificate authentication without problems.

**Edit2:**

The classes generated by Eclipse:

```
public class NfseWSServiceLocator extends org.apache.axis.client.Service implements NfseWSService {
}

public interface NfseWSService extends javax.xml.rpc.Service {
}
```

And the class generated by Axis2:

```
public class NfseWSServiceStub extends org.apache.axis2.client.Stub {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

"Untrusted Server Certificate Chain" means that your client doesn't trust the server certificate that is trying to establish a connection. In order to properly configure a HTTPS enabled communication scenario, both communication parties must trust each other.

The [RFC 5246](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246) defines the following:

**unknown_ca**

```
  A valid certificate chain or partial chain was received, but the
  certificate was not accepted because the CA certificate could not
  be located or couldn't be matched with a known, trusted CA.  This
  message is always fatal.
```

Usually is the client that requires to trust the server certificate chain to establish the connection, since the server could be operating in anonymous mode not requesting a client certificate from the peer.

Comment: If I run the application from zero, both work.
Steps:
-Start application
-Consume webservice without certificate authentication
-Work ok

-Stop and start application again
-Consume webservice with certificate authentication
-Work ok

It does not work only if I try to consume the second webservice without restarting application.